# Swift Layout programmatically with constraints or relative size

Tags: swift, uiview, uibutton, uilabel, constraints

I decided to do my app programmatically without the storyboard.
I added all UIElements (buttons, frames, images...) not with constraints to my project but with relative height. For example i said 
button.frame.height = view.frame.height / 24
button.frame.width = view.frame.width / 3
and so on...

Is this okay or should i do it with constraints?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely use constraints and AutoLayout. You can use system API for this or check other popular libraries like SnapKit or Lyt.

Comment: no problem, don't forget to check my answer as correct ;)